# Check if user is part of a group in Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I know Facebook has the Graph API that does this work, but now there is now a problem. To access this kind of information you should go through verification process and it is now suspended for individuals, as the say in developers site:
"Individual Verification Paused
Due to coronavirus (COVID-19), we have temporarily paused Individual Verification to focus our reviewers on efforts that help keep people informed and safe. We know this review step is important and will resume it as soon as we can"

Is there any way (not manual, but via software) to do this check without the Graph API for a public group? Also fetching the full list of the group members could be a possible solution, but I can't figure out a way to do this without their API

Comment: Anything not using the API would likely boil down to scraping the data directly from the website - and that is explicitly not allowed.

Comment: @04FS Thank you. Do you know any way to contact someone from the support and ask when they will come back verifying individuals? I think they are very bad on this side, strange for being a social network....

Comment: When they start processing individual verifications again, they will probably announce that through the usual channels (dev blog, …)